# How to collapse a text block in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can i collapse/visible a text block when i click to another text block?
I have 2 text block: one of them is always visible and the other one initial is collapsed. When i press on first text block , the second one make visible and so one.
I make it in Silverlight4 for a WP7 app.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have tried setting the code in TextBlock MouseLeftButtonDown/Up event

```
if (TextBlock1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
{ 
TextBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
TextBlock2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
else{
TextBlock2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
TextBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

You can hook up the MouseleftButtonUp and Down events for the TextBlock in Both SL and WP7.